# Linq and C#, Skipping records, casting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting

I'm trying to skip and take from a query, but get the casting errors:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<tblComment>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<tblComment>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<tblComment>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<tblComment>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

On the lines:

```
if(ToSkip > 0)
    q = q.Skip(ToSkip);
if(ToTake > 0)
    q = q.Take(ToTake);
```

Here's the full method, any help is appreciated!  All I'm trying to do is filter the records returned down if they are specified to do so.

Also, is this a good way of doing it, or will the database return ALL the records every time?  Ie, will it fetch all the records, THEN do the skip and take?  I want to make it efficient.

```
/// <summary>
/// Fetches all comments from a category
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Category">Category ID of comments to fetch</param>
/// <param name="Identifier">Identifier ID for category</param>
/// <param name="ToTake">How many to take in query. 0 = all</param>
/// <param name="ToSkip">How many to skip.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Comment[] FetchCommentsByNewest(int Category, int Identifier, int ToSkip, int ToTake)
{
    Comment[] Comments = new Comment[1];

    using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        // Loop each comment and insert newest first to array
        var q = (from c in db.tblComments where c.CategoryID == Category && c.IdentifierID == Identifier orderby c.PostDate descending select c);
        if(ToSkip > 0)
            q = q.Skip(ToSkip);
        if(ToTake > 0)
            q = q.Take(ToTake);
        Comments = new Comment[q.Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var Rec in q)
        {

            i++;
        }
    }

    return Comments;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always bypass it by changing the code into this:

```
var q = (
   from c in db.tblComments 
   where c.CategoryID == Category && c.IdentifierID == Identifier 
   orderby c.PostDate descending select c
)
.Skip(ToSkip > 0 ? ToSkip : 0)
.Take(ToTake > 0 ? ToTake : int.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same logic as ChrisF showed and finish the statement with return q.ToArray() or if you need a model class e.g. Comment
then use something like AutoMapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/

or

```
return q.select( x=>  new Comment{Name = x.Name, Description = x.Description}).ToArray();
```

**Note:** the ToArray or ToList() will cause the query to be executed.

Comment: How will this perform if there are millions of rows in the database?

Comment: thats why in most cases its better to write a view or stored proc. instead of creating object as in my example. If noted u say ChrisF code should implement prior to my return statement. Now the performance of EF4, Linq-2-SQL is another topic altogether.